# Java: Private Inner Classes being returned to external code

Tags: java, list, private, internal

I just started learning Java very recently, coming from a C# background.

When I started using Collections, I noticed that **Arrays.asList()** returns an `ArrayList<T>` object.

What I don't understand, is, however, that according to the code listing at '[docjar](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Arrays.java.html)' (line 2834) labels `ArrayList<T>` as *private*.

How can I be using an object that has been explicitly marked as hidden from me? Or (and this is what I suspect), does *private* have some sort of different meaning to the one I'm assuming?

(Also, I note that that class is marked as static, which also confuses me, but I'll ask that in a separate question)

---

Edit: Example in C# that throws up a compiler error:

```
public class PubClass {
        private class Blah {

        }

        public Blah GetBlah() {
            return new Blah();
        }
}
```

Gives: *Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'Namespace.PubClass.Blah' is less accessible than method 'Namespace.PubClass.GetBlah()'*

Comment: It's private, yes, but once it is returned from the method, it's yours to do with as you wish, the same as any "getter" method.

Comment: But if it's private how can I use its methods and fields? Doesn't that break the security? Or, another way of putting it: What's the point of labelling it as private? (If you see what I'm getting at)

Comment: No, you're confusing the visibility of a reference variable with the reference or object itself. While the reference variable is and will always be private, the object or reference itself doesn't care about this or know about this. If it is returned from a method, it can be used. This is no different from C#. References are neither private nor public. Only variables can be one or the other.

Comment: I just tried it in C# and it threw up a compiler error, I'll edit my question to show the example I tried

Comment: Your example shows a private class, not a private field -- and that makes for a ***big*** difference. The ArrayList class *itself* is not private, is it?

Comment: But ArrayList<E> is a private class and asList() returns an ArrayList<E>, just the same as my example, I thought? What's different?

Comment: @Motig I believe the discrepancy comes from the return type, as you cannot have a public method that returns a class of unknown type (to the rest of the program). The `asList` method actually returns a `List<T>`, a public superclass of the defined `ArrayList<T>`.

Comment: Yes, thank you purtip31, that's what jeffrey said below too, and what I didn't see/understand. Thanks.

Comment: I think that the private ArrayList class is present mainly to allow for a serialization number.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It's also present to allow the `RandomAccess` flag to be in place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ArrayList` that is returned to you implements `List` and all of the methods contained in that interface. Since `List` is public, you know about those methods and can call on them.

The reason that `ArrayList` is private is because there is no reason for it to be public: It doesn't provide any additional functionality other than what the `List` interface provides.

/edit
Your example doesn't mimic what's going on here:

```
public interface List<T> {
    /** snip */
}

public class Arrays {
    private static class ArrayList<T> implements List<T> {
        /** snip */
    }

    public <T> List<T> asList(T... arr) {
        return new ArrayList<>(arr);
    }
}
```

In your example, you are trying to return an instance of a private class which the outside caller has no knowledge of. In the `Arrays` example, the object being returned is actually a `List` (take a look at the return type), not a private `ArrayList`.

Comment: Ahhh, I see; so it's returning 'something that conforms to the interface List<T>, but you don't need to know what that is', rather than the object itself, I understand now, thank you

Comment: Out of interest, if ArrayList<E> provided its own extra method that wasn't defined by the List<T> interface (for example: extraMethod()); would I be able to use that? Or not (I guess not)?

Comment: @Motig You would not be able to use it, nor should you try to (with reflection). If the maker of the `ArrayList` class wanted you to be able to use that method, they would've made the class public.

Answer (score 1):

Private means that the class/field/method marked as private is only accessible in the current scope - the class that it is defined in. This means that you, from the outside, cannot instantiate a new ArrayList, as given in the Arrays class. However, members within the class can make use of the class, as the `asList(T... a)` method does.

The return type is actually a `List<T>`, a superclass of `ArrayList<T>`, so you can make use of that as it is a public class, with methods known to your program.

The class is marked as static because it does not have to be dynamic; the definition of the class does not change with each new instance of `Arrays`.

Comment: Firstly, List<T> is an interface, not a class, no? So I can't create an instance of a List<T>? Therefore it must be an ArrayList<T>? Also, I think, in that case, that the meaning of static is different between the languages

Comment: @Motig You cannot create a new instance of `List<T>`, but you can create new instances of classes that implement List<T> and store them in a List<T> container - the only accessible methods would be those defined in List<T>, as they must be implemented. See [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming).

Comment: I understand that I can use any object that conforms to the List<T> interface as a List<T>, but just not how the JVM is accessing the actual implementation defined in ArrayList<E> if that implementation is marked as private; though I suppose that's a difference between private access to the programmer and private access to the runtime

Answer (score 0):

Private just means that it isn't accessible outside of the class via its interface. E.g. you couldn't do something like: `myObject.m_privateVariable`. All that has happened is the `asList` 'getter' is returning a reference to the private variable, therefore exposing it through a controlled way.

Using accessors (see [mutator methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accessor)) allows the class to control access to that data. For example, you might to do some operation on private variable before returning it, which you wouldn't be able to do in one call if you let the world have direct access to all the member variables.